# 'Lightbox' with a php page inside, gracefully opens page in new tab if Javascript off

Tags: javascript, popup, lightbox, modal-dialog, html4

This is for the usual PHP/SQL/html/CSS type of webdev. Site might be visited by users with old phone browsers etc.

The popup box will contain 'interactive' forms in the sense that user enters data, clicks a button; if there was a problem with the form, the user can correct it with the popup still there.

The goal is to simply have a complete flow of text where some words are linked to electronics-calculation forms, code syntax-checking textareas, simulators. *(A great analogy is the Try-It editor on W3Schools. Like that, but allow it to pop-up modally instead of always in a new tab like theirs.)*

So: I'm looking for suggestions for

a) A generic 'popup box' with tight code, using a minimum of frameworks etc that does this,
b) The correct way to type links that old browsers won't throw up on (if no Javascript support, it should be 'transparent') and default to target="_blank" or similar.
c) HTML4 support is a big plus (CSS1/2/3 is all fine, as long as it doesn't rely heavily on CSS2/3 for crucial parts of the popup to 'function')

Probably I'm being picky here, it's just I lost my bookmark to that excellent list of Lightbox alternatives with required frameworks, total codesize and featureset. :) Also, I haven't tried them all! Do you know which one I'm thinking of?

So basically, it's name-dropping time! :) Which one do you like for the reasons a/b/c above? Give me the ones you think excel!

Edit: Could be many correct answers I guess, but I've narrowed it down to few, I think. First one gets the coveted checkmark. Anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Not sure if qualifies to your specifications, but I just wanted to share my fav lightbox.

Comment: Thanks, I liked the alert event messaging of it. It needs AJAX for a non-iframe HTML-popup though, but maybe they all do? (Side note, I'm looking for a slider plugin for Wordpress that fades photos seemlessly from one to the other without anything else, but that's probably better for a fresh question.)

Comment: Marked as the answer, since it became the only one. I really thought there'd be some more suggestions, but anyway. :)